# How to fix urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> Error

Tags: python-2.7, kubernetes, sentry

I'm currently running Sentry in Kubernetes with auto certificate generation using let's encrypt and cert-manager. When Sentry attempts to send an error to the sentry server, the following error is thrown:

```
urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)> (url: https://example.host.com/)
```

I have verified that the correct python packages for 2.7.15 have been installed. Packages include `certifi`, `urllib2` along with the dependencies.

Turning off TLS Verification works, but this is a last resort. Security is very important even though this is an internally hosted service.

Answer (score 1):

It has been my experience that even the most up-to-date `ca-certificates` packages sometimes don't contain all [3 Let's Encrypt certificates](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/). The solution(?) is to download them into the "user-controlled" certificate directory (often `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`) and then re-run [`update-ca-certificates`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html):

```sh
# the first one very likely is already in your chain,
# but including it here won't hurt anything
for i in isrgrootx1.pem.txt lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem.txt letsencryptauthorityx3.pem.txt
do
    curl -vko /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`basename $i .pem.txt`.crt \
        https://letsencrypt.org/certs/$i
done
update-ca-certificates
```

The ideal outcome would be to do that process for every Node in your cluster, and then volume mount the *actual* ssl directory into the containers, so every container benefits from the latest certificates. However, I would guess just doing it in the affected containers could work, too.

Answer (score 0):

`yum update ca-certificates.noarch` did the trick for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).